# Cannot resolve field "id"

Tags: python, классы

Разработка на bottle.py + mongoengine. Есть базовый класс:

```
    class BaseMetaDocument(Document): 
        _id = ObjectIdField(required = True, title = u'ИД', readonly = True, order = 0)
        unit = StringField(required = True, max_length = 255, default = settings.UNIT, title = u'Наша организация', readonly = True, order = 1000)
        name = StringField(required = True, unique_with = 'unit', max_length = 255, title = u'Наименование', order = 10)
        active = BooleanField(required = True, default = True, title = u'Состояние', order = 20)

        meta = {
            'abstract': True,
            'allow_inheritance': True        
            }
```

от которого потом создается подкласс, например:

```
    class iGroup(BaseMetaDocument):
        parent = ReferenceField('self', title = u'Родительская группа', order = 100)
        public = BooleanField(required = True, default = True, title = u'Публичная', order = 101) #?!#
        users = ListField(ReferenceField(iUser, reverse_delete_rule = PULL), title = u'Список пользователей', order = 102)

        meta = {
            'collection': 'iGroup'
            }
```

Чтобы вывести на форму, собираю словарь:

```
    for k, v in objectInfo._fields.iteritems():
        info = {}
        ftype = type(v)
        info = dict(title = v.title, name = k, type = ftype.__name__, 
                    value = objectInfo[k], required = v.required, 
                    readonly = getattr(v, 'readonly', False), order = getattr(v, 'order', 500))
        newObjectInfo.append(info)
```

Но получаю ошибку: Cannot resolve field "id". Если из базового класса удалить поле *_id = ObjectIdField(required = True, title = u'ИД', readonly = True, order = 0)*, то всё работает корректно, единственное, нужно отдельно в словарь нужно отдельно добавлять _id. что не совсем удобно.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать имя переменной без нижнего подчеркивания.

Comment: Это базовое поле, я пробовал, появляются ошибки уровнем "выше".

Comment: Вообще, я пытался переопределить _id. для того чтобы добавить атрибуты "title = u'ИД', readonly = True, order = 0". Может это можно сделать по другому?!